# Right way to use flask.current_app() in external modules?

Tags: python, flask

I have some code:

### application.py:

```
from forms import MyForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def index():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print('Form submited')
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

### forms.py:

```
from flask import current_app
from flask_wtf import Form
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileAllowed

class MyForm(Form):
    image = FileField('Image',
            [FileAllowed(current_app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS'],
            'Wrong extension.')])
```

But I get next error `RuntimeError: working outside of application context`

I get some working variants with using circular import statements or with import statements in the middle of the code(or just import config.py =D) but how can I fix it in <strike>pythonic</strike>Flask way?

Answer (score 0):

Since `image` is a class attribute, it gets run when you do `from forms import MyForm`. This fails cause `current_app` is a [proxy](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/appcontext/) that is valid only once the app is run.

The right thing to do would be to just move the import statement to inside `index()`. This guarantees that it gets run only during a request, which guarantees that the app is alive.

Comment: Using imports in middle of file not recommended by PEP8.
In this case easier to just import `config.py` directly w/o using `app.config`, but perhaps exists an another good way.

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/ for a few reasons that using the config file directly isn't always the best idea. If your app is gonna be small then maybe it isn't a bad idea, but in most large applications its never a good idea to use the config file directly.